# Как прижать div к низу родительского блока?

Tags: position, html, css

Есть такой html-код:

```
<div id="mainblock">
    <div class="innerblock">
        <div><img src="mypic.jpg">Какой то текст под картинкой</div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a href="#">гиперссылка</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerblock">
        <div class="info"><img src="mypic.jpg">Какой то текст под картинкой</div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a href="#">гиперссылка</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Для mainblock задан background: #FE4C4C. Все картинки имеют одинаковый размер, а "какой-то текст" может быть любым (в каждом блоке свой). Количество таких блоков может быть любым.  Как сделать так, чтобы блок info был прижат кверху, а bottom книзу?

Comment: к низу innerblock ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="mainblock" style="position: relative">
```

У блока `info`  поставить атирбут `style="position: absolute; top: 0px;"`

а у

```
bottom style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;"
```

Comment: Пробовал так. Высота блока mainblock становится равной нулю

Comment: Если делаю как предложено в ответе 1, высота блока mainblock становится равной нулю. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как решить проблему?

Comment: ммм поставить высоту у блока .innerblock стилями как вариант, и я бы ставила бы у него position: relative; ведь если mainblock родительский, все .info будут вверху относительно него, аналогично .bottom тоже

Comment: Если поставить фиксированной высоту блока - это не совсем подойдет, поскольку информация в блоках будет выводиться из базы данных, т.е., объем текста в блоке с class="info" может меняться